# what is the size of an abstract class and why can't we create objects of an abstract class?

Tags: c++, oop, abstract-class

what is the size of an abstract class and why can't we create objects of an abstract class?

Comment: You need to do two things. First, accept answers for all the questions you have asked. Second, read a bit on Object Oriented Programming. :) If you know WHY you needed an abstract class, you would not be asking why you cannot create an object out of it. Anyway See the answer Oli has posted :)

Comment: Homework is due in a few hours, yes or no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because otherwise it wouldn't be "abstract".  The whole point of an abstract base class is that it is not meaningful to instantiate it; instead one must define derived subclasses, and instantiate them instead.

<s>Abstract classes, therefore, have no size (but that's not to say that they don't contribute to the size of its derived subclasses).</s>

Comment: Eh… C++ abstract bases can have state; maybe some languages forbid it but in C++ this can actually be useful. (Also, C++ has abstract classes besides abstract bases, such as traits types.)

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Indeed, they can have state (i.e. member variables).  But my point was that you can't use `sizeof` on an abstract class, which in fact turns out to be wrong!  Correcting answer now...